# Desinstalar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows

Alguien sabe o me puede dar una recomendación sobre como desinstalar `Android Studio`, de una manera al 100% quitar el sdk y demás componentes que genera el mismo Android.

Quiero desinstalar, porque me generaba muchas veces unos errores con el SDK, eran solucionables pero molestaban.

Y también si alguien sabe como instalarlo correctamente.
En Windows 10 y por si preguntan tengo 8GB RAM 
Muchas gracias

Comment: que tal usar el desisntalador de windows? o bien busca la carpeta y lo eliminas, en tu direcotrio de usuario tambien busca toda referencia a android-studio y delete.

Comment: En este caso la versión de Windows y la RAM no es importante.

Comment: pues ami me da muchos problemas al momento de acer un dispositivo virtual dice que no puedo vere si volviendolo a instalar ya instale el intel haxm y no puedo hacer un dispositivo vitual :( y tengo w7 ram 8 y segun mi procesador si tiene vt-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes desinstalarlo desde el mismo programa de desinstalación o el panel de control, y sobre los sdk solo los borras del disco, tuve el mismo problema con la versión 1 de android studio, ahora tengo la versión 2 que está excelente.

PD: También tengo W 10 y 8GB de RAM

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que irte al panel de control, al programas y caracteristicas y desde ahí buscas en la lista Android Studio y le das a desinstalar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes localizar la carpeta de configuraciones de Android Studio, ésta guarda las configuraciones del IDE aunque sea desinstalado. Localizala en tu carpeta de Usuario (La que tiene tu nombre) y elimínala. De igual manera la carpeta del SDK. Luego puedes instalar de nuevo el Android Studio desde cero.

La forma correcta de instalarlo es con el ejecutable que está en la página oficial de google e indicarle que baje el SDK necesario automáticamente. Necesitas una buena conexión a internet para evitar errores durante la descarga.

Answer (score -1):

Actualmente la mejor manera de **eliminar Android Studio** en Windows es mediante el Panel de Control, esto para evitar dejar referencias en el sistema operativo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a **eliminar Android SDK** lo mejor es encontrar su ubicación para eliminarlo, esto lo puedes realizar desde Android Studio, ve a
`File` > `Settings` > `Android SDK` y revisa en `Android SDK Location` la ubicación del SDK, puedes borrar sin problema el folder donde se encuentra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]